# Django: Filtering query with foreign key not working

Tags: python, django, django-models, filter, foreign-keys

I want to filter a query with a foreign key, but it doesn't seem to want to recognize it. `status` can either be **`'open'`** or **`'closed'`**.

**models.py**

```
class Status(models.Model):
    status = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=100)

class Incident(models.Model):
    incident_date_reported = models.DateField('Date Reported', default=timezone.now)
    status = models.ForeignKey(Status, default="open")
```

**views.py**

```
def index(request):

    template = "index.html"                 
    form = IncidentSearchForm(request.GET)

    if request.method == 'GET':

        form = IncidentSearchForm()

        ############## MY QUERY THAT DOESN'T LIKE THE FOREIGN KEY #############
        incident_list = Incident.objects.filter(status = 'open').order_by('-incident_date_reported')
        #######################################################################

       context = {  "form": form,
                    "incident_list": incident_list
                  }

        return render(request, template, context)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `status` is a model by itself, so you should do this:

```
incident_list = Incident.objects.filter(status__status='open').order_by('-incident_date_reported')
```

Also I think your design doesn't make much sense. If you only need a string as status on `Incident`, you don't need the model `Status`, just take the `status` field to `Incident`, and your old query would work.

**Edit:**
If you want to restrict your selections to be a certain set, you should consider using `choices`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#choices

Then your model becomes:

```
class Incident(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ('open',   'Open'),
        ('closed', 'Closed'),
        # some other statuses go here
    )
    incident_date_reported = models.DateField('Date Reported',
                                              default=timezone.now)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=20,
                              choices=STATUS_CHOICES,
                              default='open')
```

Comment: I still can't get it to work. Also I wanted to make the data more strict so the user only had so many available options to choose from (in this case 2, hopefully more in the future) which is why I made Status a model. The `__` should work.... idk

Comment: *How* does it not work? What do you see? What errors so you get?

Comment: I updated your answer. Please read the django doc reference for more information.